# How can I set the sampling rate in a Movesense device?

Tags: ios

I can subscribe to the acceleration or angular velocity values with the [movesense](/questions/tagged/movesense) mobile libraries, but is there a way to change the sampling rate of the sensor?

Answer (score 0):

The new movesense-device-lib (released today) has the new sensor API's that make it possible. The API's provide convenient and generic way to access all the "fast" sensors: Accelerometer, Gyroscope and Magnetic field. The paths have also been changed to make them less verbose (saves flash memory).

Here's a small intro on how the new API's work:

1. For each sensor there is a resource under root */Meas*. */Meas/Acc*, */Meas/Gyro* and */Meas/Magn* and they all work the same way.
2. Under the sensors root there is an *Info* resource that returns available sample rates as well as ranges. This is the result from GET'ing the */Meas/Acc/Info*:

   ```
   {
   "SampleRates" : [13,26,52,104,208],
   "Ranges" : [2,4,8,16]
   }
   ```
3. Also under the sensors root there is a *Config* resource when one can GET & PUT the sensors global settings. At the moment the only setting in Accelerometer is *GRange*.
4. The data can be only *SUBSCRIBED* (no more GET in API), and the sample rate wanted is set as URL parameter: */Meas/Acc/{SampleRate}* where the *{SampleRate}* is one of the values from the *Info* resource.
5. The sbuscribed data is returned in the object of the form: *{timestamp, array of FloatVector3D's}*. Different sample rates can return different number of measurements per notification in the array.

**Word of caution:** We have tested the accelerometer upto 208 Hz (as of today) so even if the API advertises higher rates, we have not yet tested how far we can push the sensor in practice.

*Full Disclosure: I work for Movesense team*